# why checkbox is not checked in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui, semantic-ui-react, react-final-form

I am using `react final form` but I am not able to `checked` the `checkbox`. I do not know what I am doing wrong. Here is my
[Code](https://codesandbox.io/s/friendly-roentgen-r2tlt)

```
const AppWithIconToggle = ({ input }) => {
  console.log("ddd", !!input.value);
  return (
    <div>
      <SForm.Checkbox
        checked={!!input.value}
        name={input.name}
        toggle
        onChange={(e, { checked }) => input.onChange(checked)}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the `checked` property of your `SForm.Checkbox` receives `undefined`. You are passing a wrong property (`input.value`) which is undefined so `!!undefined` is always `false`. Change it to `input.checked` then it works as expected:

```
const AppWithIconToggle = ({ input }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <SForm.Checkbox
        checked={!!input.checked}
        name={input.name}
        toggle
        onChange={(e, { checked }) => input.onChange(checked)}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Sirwan mentioned. your `!!undefined` is always return `false`

Try using [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) hook

```js
// import 'useState'
import React, { useState } from "react"

const AppWithIconToggle = ({ input }) => {
  // initial check value is 'false'
  const [checked, setChecked] = useState(false)
  console.log(checked)
  return (
    <div>
      <SForm.Checkbox
        checked={checked} // checked value
        name={input.name}
        toggle
        onChange={() => setChecked(!checked)} // toggle checked value onChange
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Check your [codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-cache-s2zjl)